# Validation with AngularJS

Tags: javascript, angularjs, validation

We want to make a validation with AngularJS. I have two screens, the first "Insured data" and the second "Other", which is redirected by headers, that is, if I give a `<header of uib-tab = "Other" class = "btn-sm">` me redirects to the 'Other' screen. When the 'Others' I need that the data of 'Insured data' are valid, if the valid ones can be changed of screen, if not, the header of 'Others' will be `disabled`. This is a small piece of my code:

```
<uib-tab heading="Datos del asegurado" class="btn-sm">
        <legend>Datos del Asegurado de Vida</legend>
        <div class="collapsedDetalle" >
            <div layout-gt-sm="row" class="margin-top-20">
                <md-input-container class="md-block" flex-gt-sm>
                    <label>Nombre</label>
                    <input name="nombre" ng-model="$ctrl.datos.DATOS_TOMADOR.NO_NOMBRE" required>
                </md-input-container>
                <md-input-container class="md-block" flex-gt-sm>
                    <label>Primer apellido</label>
                    <input ng-model="$ctrl.datos.DATOS_TOMADOR.NO_APELLIDO1" required>
                </md-input-container>
                <md-input-container class="md-block" flex-gt-sm>
                    <label>Segundo apellido</label>
                    <input ng-model="$ctrl.datos.DATOS_TOMADOR.NO_APELLIDO2" required>
                </md-input-container>
            </div>
        </div>
    </uib-tab>  
    <uib-tab heading="Otros" class="btn-sm">
        <legend>Modalidad</legend>
        <div class="collapsedDetalle">
            <div layout="row">
                <div flex-gt-sm="50">
                    <label>Modalidad</label>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </uib-tab>
```

It would have to be validated if the name, first surname and second surname are filled. I tried to do this:

```
<uib-tab name="datosAsegurado" heading="Datos del asegurado" class="btn-sm">
            <legend>Datos del Asegurado de Vida</legend>
            <div class="collapsedDetalle" >
                <div layout-gt-sm="row" class="margin-top-20">
                    <md-input-container class="md-block" flex-gt-sm>
                        <label>Nombre</label>
                        <input name="nombre" ng-model="$ctrl.datos.DATOS_TOMADOR.NO_NOMBRE" required>
                        <span style="color:red" ng-show="datosAsegurado.nombre.$dirty && datosAsegurado.nombre.$invalid">
                        <span ng-show="datosAsegurado.nombre.$error.required">Nombre requerido</span>
                    </md-input-container>
                    <md-input-container class="md-block" flex-gt-sm>
                        <label>Primer apellido</label>
                        <input ng-model="$ctrl.datos.DATOS_TOMADOR.NO_APELLIDO1" required>
                    </md-input-container>
                    <md-input-container class="md-block" flex-gt-sm>
                        <label>Segundo apellido</label>
                        <input ng-model="$ctrl.datos.DATOS_TOMADOR.NO_APELLIDO2" required>
                    </md-input-container>
                </div>
            </div>
        </uib-tab>  
        <uib-tab ng-disabled="datosAsegurado.$invalid" heading="Otros" class="btn-sm">
            <legend>Modalidad</legend>
            <div class="collapsedDetalle">
                <div layout="row">
                    <div flex-gt-sm="50">
                        <label>Modalidad</label>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </uib-tab>
```

In the first header I assign a name (datosAsegurado), the name is valid in this way:

```
<span style="color:red" ng-show="datosAsegurado.nombre.$dirty && datosAsegurado.nombre.$invalid">
                        <span ng-show="datosAsegurado.nombre.$error.required">Nombre requerido</span>
```

And then to the header of 'Other' I put `ng-disabled = "datosAsegurado.$invalid"`

I know it's pretty bad, but I can not think of anything else, I hope you can help me, THANK YOU!

Answer (score 0):

I may be mistaken, but as far as I know if you want to use validations within AngularJS you have to have the relevant inputs within a form. To access the form's validations you have to reference the forms name. Also, any buttons or links that would check for validations have to be confined within those form tags. I.e.:

```
<form name='insuredAndOtherData'>
  ...
  <span style="color:red" ng-show="insuredAndOtherData.nombre.$dirty && 
  insuredAndOtherData.nombre.$invalid">
  ...
</form>
```

You can just also check that the form is valid in general by not referencing specific inputs, like this: "insuredAndOtherData.$valid".

Check out this page for more validations for both inputs specifically or forms in general: https://www.w3schools.com/angular/angular_validation.asp.